# Listeners on LinearLayout

Tags: java, android

I'm adding and removing `View`s to a `LinearLayout` dynamically.

I'm trying to check whenever a `LinearLayout`'s number of childs changes, is there such a listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [ViewGroup.OnHierarchyChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.OnHierarchyChangeListener.html).

Use it's `onChildViewAdded()` and `onChildViewRemoved()` methods with a counter to keep track of the child count of a `ViewGroup`.

You could do something like this in your `Activity`:

```
private childCount;

// ...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // ...

    final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourLayout);

    childCount = layout.getChildCount();

    layout.setOnHierarchyChangeListener(new ViewGroup.OnHierarchyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildViewAdded(View parent, View child) {
            childCount++;
          //childCount = layout.getChildCount(); //a safer but slower approach
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildViewRemoved(View parent, View child) {
            childCount--;
          //childCount = layout.getChildCount();
        }
    });
}
```

(just a rough example, you may need to implement the counter logic according to your needs)